# weak convergence imply expectation $\le$ lower limit of sequence expectation

Tags: weak-convergence, uniform-integrability

$(X_{n})$ are uniformly integrable stochastic process ,$X_{n}\xrightarrow{d}X$

Proof $E[\left | X \right |]\le \liminf_{n\to\infty}E[\left | X_{n} \right |]$

I see a way that $f_{m}(x)=\begin{cases}\left | x \right |\quad &\left | x \right |\le{m}\\m\quad &\left | x \right |>{m}\end{cases}$ , $f_{m}$ is in mon0tone rise to$\left | x \right |$ ,$f_{m}$ is bounded continuous function

so  $E[\left | X \right |]=\lim_{m \to \infty}E[f_{m}(X)]=\lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}E[f_{m}(X_{n})]\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}E[f_{m}(X_{n})]=\liminf_{n\to\infty}E[\left | X_{n} \right |]$

But I don't know why $\lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}E[f_{m}(X_{n})]\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}E[f_{m}(X_{n})]$

How did this step come about?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $f_m(x) \leq |x|$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, which implies that
$$E[f_m(X_n)] \leq E[|X_n|].$$
Taking $\liminf$ gives (by the continuous mapping theorem)
$$E[f_m(X)]\leq \liminf_n E[|X_n|].$$
This holds for every $m$. Now let $m\to \infty$ to get the result (using for example the monotone convergence theorem).

---

Another solution: if you're familiar with [Skorokhod's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem), then the result is a direct application of Fatou's lemma.

Comment: Thank you very much